# Loop over rows in file and replace values in linux command line

Tags: linux, vcf-variant-call-format

when I have multiple files with similar extensions, such as:

```
file1.txt 
file2.txt 
file3.txt 
file4.txt
```

and I have another file:

```
test.vcf
```

I want to run a command line in linux which performs an operation on the test.vcf file and all the time is using one of the 4 files with extension .txt at once I can loop over the files and write only one command instead that writing 4 different commands:

```
for i in {1..4};
do bcftools view -r file$i.txt test.vcf -o test_output$i.vcf;
done
```

this command line will use files1.txt on test.vcf and output test_output1.vcf and so on so I can use the $i to replace in the number of the file.

Now let's suppose I have only one file "file.txt" and this file has multiple columns:

```
V1 V2  V3 
a   10  c
d   19  f
g   8   i
l   4   n
```

I would like to loop over each value in column V2 and similarly instead that writing 4 command line I can just write a single command.

Any advice on this?
Thanks

Comment: [bashfaq How can I read a file field-by-field?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: sure, I take a look